# Hyperbolic Tessellations of a Pentagon in Mathematica

Tags: math, geometry, wolfram-mathematica, line

I want to implement this in Mathematica:[image]

I realize I can use ParametricPlot to get the lines, and then use the Mesh option to fill in the colors. Can anyone tell me what a general formula for the equations of these lines are? Does it generalize to a regular n-gon?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I happen to have some code lying around that will do something close to what you want and you can view that code here: http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/mathematicaGraphics/PTiling/.

A couple of comments are in order.  The ideas behind the code are all described in Saul Stahl's excellent book, The Poincare Half-Plane - specifically, the chapter on the Poincare disk.  I wrote the code to illustrate some ideas for a geometry class that I was teaching in 1999 so it must have been for version 3 or 4.  I have done nothing to try to optimize the code for any subsequent version.  Regardless, if you define the function `PTiling` on that page and then execute `PTiling[5, 2*5 - 4, 3]`, you should (after several minutes) get something like the following:

[image]

Obviously, we have just a black and white picture illustrating the boundaries of the pentagons that you want but, hopefully, this is a good start.  I think that one could use portions of disks, rather than circles, to get closer to what you want.